# Using RegEx to find and replace doubles

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I want to replace all double tokens in string with the double value appended with "c" letter. Is there an easy way to do it? I thought that the Regular Expression is the way to go

for example, I wanna change the following

```
treand60(12.3)/1010 + 1 >1010
```

with

```
treand60(12.3c)/1010c + 1c >123c
```

any suggestions

Comment: What do you consider a token for your purposes?

Comment: anything separated by Arithmetic or logical operator or ( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to look for all sequences of digits optionally ending with a decimal point and another digit sequence and then append a 'c'.  Here's an example, assuming you're using Perl (your question doesn't say):

```
$_ = 'treand60(12.3)/1010 + 1 >1010';
s/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?/$&c/g;
print;  # output is "treand60(12.3c)/1010c + 1c >1010c"
```

`\d+` is 1 or more digit and then `\.\d+` is 1 or more digit after a decimal point.  The `(?: ... )` is a [non-capturing group](http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perlretut-noncapturing.html).  The last `?` means "match zero or one of these" (i.e. it's optional).  And the `\b` means match only on word boundaries (this prevents something like "Hello123" from matching because the number comes directly after a word character).

Here is the C# equivalent:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...

string input = "treand60(12.3)/1010 + 1 >1010";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?");
string output = regex.Replace(input, (m) => m.Value + 'c');
Console.WriteLine(output);  // prints "treand60(12.3c)/1010c + 1c >1010c"
```

The lambda expression inside the [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) call is a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) which simply gets the match text and appends a 'c'.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention that I wanna do it with C#